# What is the difference between RemoteWebDriver.executeScript() and Selenium.getEval()?

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

What is the difference between this:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Object result = driver.executeScript("somefunction();");
```

and this:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
Selenium seleniumDriver = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, driver.getCurrentUrl());
String result = seleniumDriver.getEval("somefunction();");
```

I have an example when first command works and second hangs Firefox and other way around. I'd like to understand what is the difference between these two functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you want to know is in the [Selenium Webdriver Documentation](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html).
Especially the part [How Does WebDriver ‘Drive’ the Browser Compared to Selenium-RC ?](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#how-does-webdriver-drive-the-browser-compared-to-selenium-rc)

Comment: My introduction to Selenium started post version 2, but it makes much more sense from historical perspective now. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 2):

The script fragment provided will be executed as the body of an anonymous function.

```
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("somefunction();");
```

internally injects something like this into the document:

```
return function()
{ 
   somefunction(); 
}.call();
```

So essentially on webdriver, executeScript executes synchronously and can block.

Comment: From reading documentation now it seems that it is other way around. JavascriptExecutor executes scripts via native WebDriver interface, when Selenium-RC injects some javascript to do so.

Comment: True, but not in case of Java Script code. JS executes in the fashion I explained above. If you really want to understand the architecture of selenium (JS atoms et al..) read http://www.aosabook.org/en/selenium.html, selenium docs is for end users and says little about how things work under the hood.